# Pasar fecha con formato a input javascript

Tags: jquery, date, formato, javascript-import

Tengo un formulario emergente que tiene el siguiente input (entre otros):

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
  <label form="txtfechapago">Fecha Pago</label>
  <input type="date" class="form-control" name="fecpago" id="txtfechapago" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>">
</div>
```

Desde un datatable cuando hago clic en el boton de modificar abro el formulario y paso los datos pero no sé como puedo pasar la fecha en formato (Y-m-d) ya que la estoy mostrando en la tabla (d-m-y)

```
 $("#tbl_empleados tbody").on("click", ".btnmodpago", function () {
  var data = table3.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();
  $("#modal-gestionar-tema").modal("show");
  $("#txtcodpago").val(data["CodigoPago"]),
  $("#txtimporte").val(data["Importe"]);
  $("#txtimportepagado").val(data["ImportePagado"]);
  $("#txtobs").val(data["Observaciones"]);
  $("#txtfechaprevista").val("2023-03-18");
  $("#txtfechapago").val(data["FechaPago"]);
});
```

si paso el valor con el formato yyyy-mm-dd lo muestra perfectamente pero si le paso el valor en el formato que se muestra en la table dd-mm-yyyy no lo muestra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba siguiendo estos pasos.

1. Obtienes la fecha:

   ```
   var fecha = data["FechaPago"];
   ```
2. Usas al `-` como separador, almacenándolo en un array:

   ```
   var result = fecha.split("-");
   ```
3. Inviertes el array:

   ```
   var result = fecha.split("-").reverse();
   ```
4. Y vuelves a poner los `-` entre los elementos:

   ```
   var result = fecha.split("-").reverse().join("-");
   ```
5. Y el resultado final lo pones en tu input:

   ```
   $("#txtfechapago").val(result);
   ```

Comment: Genial, mil gracias!!!